# How to set up SSL

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications, ssl, jetty

I am developing a web application with GWT. Now it is running in development mode in local server with Jetty. Could anyone tell me how can I set up the SSL in this case. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wrong place to ask. Flagging to move to Server Fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully added SSL to a Jetty server in the past following the steps detailed here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL

> The following steps are required to configure Jetty for SSL:
>   Step 1: Generate or obtain a public/private key pair and x509 certificate.
>   Step 2: Optionally obtain a certificate from a known certificate authority.
>   Step 3: Load the keys and the certificates into a JSSE Keystore.
>   Step 4: Configure a JsseListener with the location and passwords for the keystore.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will loke into it.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do step 4? Where I can find that configuration xml file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about GWT's DevMode and its embedded Jetty, see http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/shell/jetty/README-SSL.txt

Answer (score 0):

I always recomend placing a general purpose web server in front of the java server. It is a reverse proxy for the dinamic html and serves directly the static media. The configurability ans flexibility of this configuration is great, and sometimes easier and faster, look at cherokee server, fast, light and has a awesome web interface for administration.

Want to add headers for cross-site ajax?, easy. Configure the *.cache.js to cache forever and the rpc calls to no-cache/private? two clicks!